# Snowflake: Conversion error of an teradata query to snow sql

Tags: sql, azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a Teradata query **(updated the fields with sample values)**:

```
select (case '-' when '-' then '-' ||'04' || ':' ||'00'
else '04' || ':' ||'00'
end (Interval hour to minute)) +
 (case
    '2400' when '2400' then 24
    else 0
end (interval hour));
```

**output : -04:00** (varchar type)

```
select (case '-' when '-' then '-' ||'04' || ':' ||'00'
else '04' || ':' ||'00'
end (Interval hour to minute)) +
 (case
    '1835' when '2400' then 24
    else 0
end (interval hour));
```

**output: 20:00** (varchar type)

Want to convert the same in snowflake, but the same output value was not able to insert in snowflake varchar column:

```
SELECT                             
(CASE SUBSTR(raw_data, 48, 1) 
 WHEN '-' THEN CONCAT('-' , SUBSTR(raw_data,49,2) , ':' , SUBSTR(raw_data,51,2))
 ELSE CONCAT(SUBSTR(raw_data,49,2) , ':' , SUBSTR(raw_data,51,2)) END) + 
 (CASE SUBSTR(raw_data,40,4)  WHEN '2400' THEN 24 ELSE 0  END)  
AS COLUMN_1
FROM
    (SELECT  temp_row.$1 as raw_data  from
           @JOB_MANAGEMENT.SNOWFALKE (file_format => 'DB.TBL_FILE_FORMAT',
            pattern=>'.*/input_file.txt') temp_table) temp;
```

Sample:

```
SELECT                             
(CASE '-' WHEN '-' 
THEN CONCAT('-' , '04 , ':' , '00')
ELSE CONCAT('04' , ':' , '00') END)  + 
(CASE '1825'  WHEN '2400' THEN 24 ELSE 0  END)
```

**Output : -04:00** (column type - varchar) -> but throwing error in snowflake.
**Numeric value '-04:00' is not recognized**

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to rewrite query 1:1, this approach focuses on rewriting the logic using [TIME_FROM_PARTS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/time_from_parts.html):

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN SUBSTR(raw_data, 48, 1) = '-'
       THEN TIME_FROM_PARTS(24-SUBSTR(raw_data,49,2)::INT, SUBSTR(raw_data,51,2)::INT, 0)
       ELSE TIME_FROM_PARTS(SUBSTR(raw_data,49,2)::INT, SUBSTR(raw_data,51,2)::INT, 0)
  END
FROM ...
```

Comment: `SELECT                             
(CASE SUBSTR(raw_data, 48, 1) WHEN '-' THEN 
 (CASE SUBSTR(raw_data,40,4)  WHEN '2400' THEN 
 TIME_FROM_PARTS(24-SUBSTR(raw_data,49,2)::INT, SUBSTR(raw_data,51,2)::INT, 0) 
 ELSE 
 CONCAT('-' , SUBSTR(raw_data,49,2) , ':' , SUBSTR(raw_data,51,2))
 END)  
 ELSE 
 (CASE SUBSTR(raw_data,40,4)  WHEN '2400' THEN 
 TIME_FROM_PARTS(24-SUBSTR(raw_data,49,2)::INT, SUBSTR(raw_data,51,2)::INT, 0) 
 ELSE 
 CONCAT(SUBSTR(raw_data,49,2) , ':' , SUBSTR(raw_data,51,2))
 END)  
 END) 
AS COLUMN_1`

Comment: Thanks, i have updated the code, but i get two results 20:00:00 and -04:00, but looking to get only hours and minutes (HH24:MI) in both the cases.